# Get error of specific function

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

I am using [odtphp library](https://github.com/cybermonde/odtphp) to create custom `.odt` file.

In this library there is a function to save the `.odt` on disk

```
public function saveToDisk($file = null)
{
    if ($file !== null && is_string($file)) {
     if (file_exists($file) && !(is_file($file) && is_writable($file))) {
         throw new OdfException('Permission denied : can\'t create ' . $file);
     }
        $this->_save();
        copy($this->tmpfile, $file);     
    } else {
        $this->_save();
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but I can not figure out how to get the error message (by exemple when the doc is already open by someone else)

I'm trying this

```
try
{
    $odf->saveToDisk('test.odt');
}
catch(OdfException $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But it give me the whole PHP error (with orange background) instead of the `Permission denied`

### Edit

This is the PHP error that I get (with orange background)

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding
='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f
; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: copy(Test.odt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
 Path\To\odtphp-master\library\Odf.php on line <i>259</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align
='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left'
 bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0012</td><td bgcolor
='#eeeeec' align='right'>262008</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='Path\To\test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\test.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.1992</td><td bgcolor
='#eeeeec' align='right'>1872248</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Odf->saveToDisk(  )</td><td title='Path\To\test.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\test.php<b>:</b>75</td><
/tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2434</td><td bgcolor
='#eeeeec' align='right'>2109632</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.copy'
 target='_new'>copy</a>
(  )</td><td title='Path\To\odtphp-master\library\Odf.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Odf.php
<b>:</b>259</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

Comment: Can you post what the error says? (the one in the orange background)

Comment: What does `echo file_exists($file);` , `echo is_file($file);` and `echo is_writable($file);` output? Also `echo get_cwd();` and check if file location in server's local file system is correct if `$file` does not contain an absolute path.

Comment: Check the file permissions (5 = read/execute access) of the folders of the full path. File should have permission 6 (writable).

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone All functions return `1` but this is not the problem. The file is well created or replaced when there is no error. I just want to manage the error if this happen

Comment: Which is the line 259? Seems to be `copy($this->tmpfile, $file);` ?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Yep. That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exception or error, you get a warning from the `copy()` function. This might happen, when you don't have permission to access `$this->tmpfile` or (after you have checked permission to overwrite an existing regular file `$file`) the file does not exist and you haven't got the permission to create it.

You could modify your condition

```
if( file_exists($file) && !(is_file($file) && is_writable($file))
    || ( !file_exists($file) && !is_writable(dirname($file)) ) )
```

I assume the existence of $this->tmpfile has already been ensured in other place of the class.(?)